# URLResource in springboot soap request

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, ws-security

I am using spring boot to digitally sign certificate. Here is my code snippet.

```
@Bean
public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor() throws Exception {
    Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();
    // set security actions
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementActions("Timestamp Signature");
    // sign the request
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementPassword("password");
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureCrypto(getCryptoFactoryBean().getObject());
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureKeyIdentifier("DirectReference");

    return securityInterceptor;
}

@Bean
public CryptoFactoryBean getCryptoFactoryBean() throws IOException {
    CryptoFactoryBean cryptoFactoryBean = new CryptoFactoryBean();
    cryptoFactoryBean.setKeyStorePassword("password");
    cryptoFactoryBean.setKeyStoreLocation(new UrlResource("http://hostname/cert.p12"));
    return cryptoFactoryBean;
}
```

I am getting below error:

`Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL [http://hostname/cert.p12] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: http://hostname/cert.p12
    at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:215)
    at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:53)
    at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getFile(UrlResource.java:213)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.support.CryptoFactoryBean.getResourcePath(CryptoFactoryBean.java:91)`

Is there any way to use URL in cryptoFactoryBean.setKeyStoreLocation?

Thanks,

Comment: Apparently not. As the `CryptoFactoryBean` requires it to be on the filesystem (due to the usage of `getFile` which only works for local resources).

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. Do you know other than CryptoFactoryBean what else can be used in this scenario?